# Converting string to datetime in C#

Tags: c#, string, datetime, type-conversion

There are several threads on similar topic with several solution but none of them are marked as answer.

I have a string and would like to convert into DateTime

```
 string str = "12-3-2013 12-09-10 PM";
 DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "MM-dd-yyyy HH-mm-ss tt", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

This gives an error. Is there something to do with CultureInfo? How does CultureInfo affect the output?

Comment: [Put a 0 in front of the 3 (day)](http://dotnetfiddle.net/s2OSJc)

Comment: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: "This gives an error" is not a problem description, and is not useful. Please provide the **exact error message** you're getting. It's right in front of you, and there is absolutely no reason not to include it in your question.

Comment: Are you *really* using a 24-hour clock *and* an am/pm designator? That would be unusual.

Comment: @JMK That worked. Thanks. But does that mean I will have to split the string to its pieces to check whether dd MM HH mm ss are represented as 1 character or 2 characters?

Comment: @JonSkeet What indicates the OP is using a 24 hour clock, couldn't 12 be midday or am I missing something? Sorry!

Comment: @JMK: The fact that they're using "HH" in the format string rather than "hh".

Comment: @bluepiranha [Using a single *d* should work fine](http://dotnetfiddle.net/wTebJQ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **dd**: The day of the month, from 01 through 31.
>
> **d**: The day of the month, from 1 through 31.

For sure day is not `dd` as is using a single digit. Also, you need to change `HH` by `hh` or remove am/pm.
Try with this

```
MM-d-yyyy hh-mm-ss tt
```

You might need to change `MM` by `M` but it's impossible to say with provided example.

Answer (score 0):

```
string str = "12-3-2013 12-09-10 PM";
Convert.ToDateTime(str);
```